# Unalias [aliasing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

Excuse the pun.

The tag [aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aliasing) is currently officially about:

> Distortion caused in analog-to-digital conversion by a too low rate of data sampling.

Not what I would have guessed! There are lots of kinds of aliasing, especially when writing software...:

- Pointer aliasing
- method aliasing
- DBMS column aliasing
- Aliasing in digital images and video (which may or may not be due to the processing of analog signals)

In fact, if you look at the question on the tag page, you'll notice that very few of them are about aliasing in analog signals!

So, what is to be done?

Options:

1. Remove `aliasing` from those naughty questions, add other tags to them.
2. Like (1.), but also rename `aliasing` into `audio-aliasing` or `d2a-aliasing` or `signal-aliasing` or whatever. The latter may let you also keep the image and video aliasing questions in there, although the name is not quite intuitive.
3. Make `aliasing` about the most popular kind of aliasing - I think that would be pointer aliasing, then back to (1.) but with a different set of questions to change.
4. Declare aliasing a "kitchen-sink"-type tag, whose use is discouraged, which is about any kind of aliasing phenomenon.
5. Delete the aliasing tag altogether, perhaps go back to (1.) but now all images need re-tagging with other tags.

Feel free to suggest other options or argue for the one you think is best. Naturally my choice of "accepted" answer will mean nothing since I'm not a moderator.

Comment: "unalias [aliasing]"? :) More on point, there is also type aliasing which also has little to do with what the intention behind the tag seems to be. Options 2 & 4 look the most appealing so far.

Comment: "very few of them are about aliasing in audio!" — Nitpicking: the description doesn't say audio; as written it equally applies to RF (software-defined radio) and other sensors/transducers. I agree it's not a _good_ general description though; it's certainly easy to produce aliasing in any signal or image "from scratch" without any ADC involved. But, questions and answers on the _general_ theory and practice of aliasing probably fit best at <https://dsp.stackexchange.com/>; here, it makes sense to break up the tag into pointers, audio, image-rendering-and-scaling… if those topics have many Qs.

Comment: We don't even seem to have a pointer-aliasing tag, which is a bit weird. There's [tag:alias], [tag:type-alias] and [tag:strict-aliasing] but they have specific meanings. I also found [tag:aliases] which seems to be a garbage tag.

Comment: I'm in favor of #2, but leaving the most popular topic on the tag. Saves some retagging work, and I can take care of those with a merge. Planning to look into this tonight or something:tm:. (For bonus points, feel free to identify what the target tag should be, and/or join in on the retagging of the questions not in the topic majority)

Comment: On dsp.stackexchange, the bag filled by Kevin may well be tagged aliasing, but over here, a better name may be freq-aliasing. This includes images (spatial frequency).

Comment: @Rainald62 Personally, I'd go for separate tags for the things that tend to be programmed differently (image processing is generally done in different contexts, styles, and APIs than audio and SDR, even if the math is the same, and 'real-time' vs 'batch' also significantly affects the programming practice).

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: Seeing how there is no opposition to option #2, could you go ahead with it?

Comment: Already have, hence the [status-completed]

Comment: That leaves the other topics. Scrolling down, the first non-pointer question I see is about (image) aliasing in a raytracer. Should we retag those [tag:antialiasing], since almost all questions about aliasing will be about how to prevent it?

Comment: I've now retagged all of those graphics questions.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine: A few things missed, I think.  [tag:aliasing] is now an alias of [tag:pointer-aliasing], but its tag wiki is still about analog-to-digital conversion.  Also [tag:adc] suggests using [tag:aliasing] which is no longer right.

Comment: @NateEldredge Fixed